# Xamarin Forms button click event crashes when running

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, crash

I'm editing an application in Xamarin targeting: Windows, iOS and Android.

In the portable project, when editing the xaml file I added this button:

```
<Button 
    x:Name="Marker_Detection" 
    Text="Marker Detection" 
    Grid.Row="0" 
    Grid.Column="0" />
```

All goes well.

Then I added the click name function for the button:

```
<Button 
    x:Name="Marker_Detection" 
    Text="Marker Detection" 
    Grid.Row="0" 
    Grid.Column="0" 
    Click="MarkerDetectionClick" />
```

The project builds fine, but crashes in the execution. It stops at the line below, in the file `App.g.i.cs`:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
        --->STOP HERE--->   
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) 
                global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
}
```

What is the solution for the this problem?

Comment: You have to show us how you add your  Click handler and the code of the click handler.

Comment: Updated my answer based on new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event is called Clicked, not Click in Xamarin Forms, so your XAML is invalid, and that's why it's failing. This should work:

```
<Button 
x:Name="Marker_Detection" 
Text="Marker Detection" 
Grid.Row="0" 
Grid.Column="0" 
Clicked="MarkerDetectionClick" />
```

You may want to set your debugging settings to break when an exception is thrown, it should give you more information about the real problem when things like this happen. Here is some info on how to do this in Visual Studio, I assume Xamarin Studio has similar settings if you're using that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx